# How to create an Angular JS Material Element via a JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material, md-card

**Problem:** I have created a webpage with an md-card that has a button. Upon clicking that button, I want another card to appear. The Problem: I cannot figure out, how to make the button of the new card work. It is not correctly formated and it has no functionality.

**Question:** What do I need to change the code to, to make it work? Thanks.

**Code:** This is my JavaScript-Code:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {

    function addMeinElement () { 
                                // create a new div element 
                                var newDiv = document.createElement("md-card");
                                document.querySelector('#myID').appendChild(newDiv);
                                newDiv.innerHTML = "<md-card-content>Oh no! Why does this button not work?<br>"+
                                                    "<md-button class='md-warn' ng-click='my_print_to_console()'>Button :( </md-button>"+
                                                    "</md-card-content>";
                                }

    $scope.my_print_to_console = function ()    {
                                                addMeinElement ();
                                                };  


});
```

This is the corresponding html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.13/angular-material.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.13/docs.css'>   
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
        <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; top:0;   height:100%;"> 
            <div style="position:fixed;width:80%;top:0;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%, 0);">
                <md-card>
                    <md-card-content>
                        <p>Click the button to hopefully create a new card with another button.</p>
                            <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="my_print_to_console()";>Button :)</md-button>
                    </md-card-content>
                </md-card>
                <div id="myID">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

<!--
Copyright 2018 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be found
in the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
-->

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.13/angular-material.js'></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because Angular not aware that this is a an Angular component. you need to wrap your HTML with [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service.

1. Add '$compile' to your module dependency
2. Wrap the code like that

> $compile('your html here')($scope);

Comment: This seems like a promising answer. However, I can't figure out where in the code to insert this modification. I tried the following, but it does not work for me. `newDiv.innerHTML = $compile("<md-card-content>test</md-card-content>")($scope);`